# Picking Multiple Attributes in XSLT

Tags: xslt

Below Is My Input XML.

```
<ServiceIncident xmlns="http://b2b.ibm.com/schema/IS_B2B_CDM/R2_2">
    <ProviderID>INC0011731</ProviderID> 
    <ProviderPriority>4</ProviderPriority>
    <WorkflowStatus>NEW</WorkflowStatus>
    <ServiceProvider1>
       <Person Role="AffectedUser">
          <ContactID>ITELLA_BRIDGE_USER</ContactID>
          <FullName>Chad Whaley</FullName>      
       </Person>
    </ServiceProvider1>
```

Below is my XSL

```
<xsl:template match="r2:Person/@Role">      
   <xsl:attribute name="Role">Owner</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="r2:Person/@Role">
   <xsl:attribute name="Role">ReportedBy</xsl:attribute>        
</xsl:template>
```

My issue is i want to get these 2 fields in output replacing the old one in input.Iam able to get one value in output but iam not getting other value.

Comment: It is an error to have two templates matching exactly the same thing in this way. Can you show the output you are actually expecting in this instance, as that would make it clearer what you are trying to achieve. Thanks!

Comment: You are also trying to create two attributes with the same name: if allowed, this would result in an invalid (not well-formed) document.

Answer (score 0):

I put on a space as a separator between attributes:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:r2="http://b2b.ibm.com/schema/IS_B2B_CDM/R2_2" exclude-result-prefixes="r2">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="r2:Person">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="Role">Owner ReportedBy</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```