# Adding Attributes issues in xsl

Tags: xslt

The Below is my input xml

```
             <ServiceIncident xmlns="http://b2b.ibm.com/schema/IS_B2B_CDM/R2_2">
             <ProviderID>INC0011731</ProviderID> 
             <ProviderPriority>4</ProviderPriority>
             <WorkflowStatus>NEW</WorkflowStatus>
            <ServiceProvider1>
               <Person Role="AffectedUser">
               <ContactID>ITELLA_BRIDGE_USER</ContactID>
               <FullName>Chad Whaley</FullName>      
               </Person>
           </ServiceProvider1>
```

Below is my xsl code iam using but iam not getting the required output.

```
           <xsl:template match="r2:Person/@Role">        
           <xsl:attribute name="Role">ReportedBy</xsl:attribute>         
           </xsl:template>
```

My problem is i want to get onemore person Role="ReportedBy" in output under serviceprovider root tag and Person Role="AffectedUser" should not replaced with this value.This value should also be there in output.

Comment: How about reading the comments and answer to your last question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21902249/picking-multiple-attributes-in-xslt) before asking a new one?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I see. I initially misread the request (or it was edited since my first response).

Since XSLT is a programming language there are multiple possible answers and you haven't given us enough information about your requirements to prefer one or another. Here's one suggestion:

Assuming your stylesheet is based on the identity transform with transforms spelling out the exceptions (one of the better ways to write most stylesheets), add another identity template modified to (a) match on the Person-with-appropriate-role element, and (b) after processing that element, insert another which has the new information.

```
<xsl:template match="r2:Person[@Role!='AffectedUser']">
    <xsl:copy/>>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <Person Role="ReportedBy"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This will **replace** the existing @Role attribute - not **add** another one, as requested (ill-advisedly, IMHO) by the OP.

Comment: Ah, I see what they're asking. Corrected.